# sqlite3.exe Nuget package installation failure - .NET framework compatibility?

Tags: sqlite, nuget

I am trying to install the Nuget package for the `sqlite3.exe` command line program in a C# project targeting Framework 4.7.2. The package is:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite3-command-line-shell/

When I try this from within VS2015 it errors out with:

> Could not install package 'sqlite3-command-line-shell 1.0.1'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but **the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework**.

Now, this package *literally only installs the .exe file*. There are no .NET dependencies whatsoever. So I don't see the rationale for this error.

Is there something wrong with the Nuget package? Or is there an option I've missed to work around this maybe?

---

The NUSPEC file inside the NUPKG file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>sqlite3-command-line-shell</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>sqlite3 command-line shell</title>
    <authors>Darren Hale</authors>
    <owners>Darren Hale</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://www.sqlite.org/index.html</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>The sqlite3 command-line shell program.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Version 3.8.10.2 (x86) of sqlite3 command-line shell program.

Removed unnecessary files accidentally included when packing .nuspec file.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags>sqlite3 cli shell exe</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I don't see any mention of any .NET anything; but I know very little about how Nuget packages are constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite3.exe is in the root directory of the NuGet package.

It looks like you are trying to create a tools NuGet package, similar to say NUnit.ConsoleRunner. the executable would need to be in a tools directory inside the NuGet package.

The .nuspec is missing a files section, something like:

```
<files>
  <file src="sqlite3.exe" target="tools" />
</files>
```

Comment: This is not a package I am creating, just trying to use it. But that certainly could be the cause of the problem...

Comment: OK. So you cannot install it with Visual Studio. The only way to use it would be to download it and extract it, say by using `nuget install sqlite3-command-line-shell`